# Cone shape smoothening

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image][image] [image]

Hi,

I am trying to render the green cone shaped hats as you can on the pictures above, but there are weird stripes around it

I followed youtube instructions and did turn on auto smooth (30 degrees) under 'Normals' section, but it does not seem to work at all

What am I missing out and what other ways would you recommend?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smoothing algorithm fakes normals across polygons with a linear interpolation across the triangles into which they are divided  for rendering, between the vertex normals at the triangles' corners. Asking that interpolation to simulate the curvature of a surface when the triangles are very long and thin is, literally, a bit of a stretch.

To give smoothing a chance, it's better to have those triangles approach equilateral as closely as possible, and to have smooth transitions between the sizes of faces, where you want smooth transitions between interpolated normals.

[image]

Just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelling the vertex at the point a tiny amount, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevelling the base perimeter a bit, with 2 segments and a profile of 1, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cutting some edge-loops around the cone, as above. gives the smoothing algorithm more to chew on:

[image]

If you're getting really fanatical, you can delete the N-gon at the tip, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> *Face menu > Grid Fill* it, putting a couple more edge loops in there to aid the transition:

[image]

.. and even Catmull-Clark *Subdivide* the result... It depends on how far you want to go.

[image]

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late accept, thank you for the detailed answer!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the hat object and choosing `Shade Smooth` from the `Object Context Menu` (<kbd>Right-click</kbd>, or <kbd>W</kbd> key) then Auto-Smooth Normals should function as intended.

[image: Shade smooth]

You can also set individual faces to have smooth shading in Edit Mode, using the `Face Context Menu`.

[image: Smooth Faces]